# Convert JavaScript UTC datetime to local YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone, iso8601

I get data from a database as an ISO-8601 date time string in UTC and then I need to convert it to a local date string in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

This code works but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it...

```js
const zeroPad = n => n < 10 ? '0' + n : n
const d = new Date('2021-07-06T01:00:00.000Z') // UTC 1 AM
const month = zeroPad(d() + 1)
const date = zeroPad(d())
const result = `${d.getFullYear()}-${month}-${date}`
console.log(result); // US/Eastern 8 PM - date is 1 day earlier
```

It feels a bit unwieldy but am trying to avoid the overhead of external libraries.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [*toLocaleDateString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) as the format you're after is given by language en-CA (and maybe others):

```js
console.log(
  new Date('2021-07-06T01:00:00.000Z').toLocaleDateString('en-CA')
);
```

The caveat with any *toLocale** method is that you aren't guaranteed that all implementations will return the same format and may fallback to some implementation dependent format. So don't use it if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

The second line is redundant. The `Date` object is intrinsically UTC based.  The conversion to the browser's local time zone doesn't actually happen until each call to `getMonth`, `getDate`, and `getFullYear`.  So you don't need two separate calls to the `Date` constructor.  Other than that, your code is fine.

If it seems a bit unwieldy, that's to be expected.  [Temporal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/) will make this better, but until it is available, you can either do it this way or with libraries.

Incidentally, your comment is incorrect.  London is UTC+1 in July for British Summer Time, so it would be 2AM in London for that UTC-based timestamp.